# QUnit test in Firefox 23: "TypeError: document.setUserData is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

My QUnit test suite ([source here](https://github.com/openjck/apod.js/blob/master/tests/tests.js)) is failing in Firefox 23 and later with the error `TypeError: document.setUserData is not a function`. See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruQug.png) for more information.

Mysteriously, a different test seems to fail every time, but only one test fails per page load. I see that Firefox removed setUserData, but I am not using that function in my code, nor do I see that function being used in QUnit code. What could be happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a known issue with FF and Selenium:

> Apparently, Node.setUserData is no longer supported.  The alternative
>   is to use a WeakMap
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.setUserData more
>   specifically, executeScript() fails, because the firefox driver is
>   injecting a script into the target page and then using
>   document.setUserData to communicate with that script.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5710

Comment: I did notice Selenium running into the same problem, but I am not using Selenium directly. I suppose my testing service (BrowserStack) is using Selenium, and thus causing this error to appear...